# Error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file

Tags: visual-c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, directx-11

I was working on a project in C++   and when i tried build it on relase mode it gives me that error:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'c:\users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project2\Release\Project2.exe'  c:\Users\xxx\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Project2\Project2\LINK   Project2

Comment: Read the error message. It says it cannot open `project2.exe`. Are you doing something that would prevent the linker from opening the file? (Maybe you have the file open somewhere else.)

Comment: Please submit an answer and accept it. That way the next person who has the problem will know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by doing the following:

1. in command prompt type msconfig and press enter.
2. Click services tab.
3. Look for "Application experience" and put tick mark (ie. Select this to enable).
4. Click ok. And restart if necessary.

Thus the problem will go forever. Build and debug your c++ projects without any disturbance.